# Replicate same tr row css in two tables side by side

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-table

I have kept two tables inside div table1 is fixed and not scrollable and table2 is scrollable. So they look like one table only.  Now I want when I select a row in the first table, both the table's selected row sets the background color. I mean if the first row is selected in table one and the background color becomes green so second table's first row should also set the background color to green

[image]

In the image, Sr No and Asin is one table and status+video is the second table.

Comment: It is hard to image what exactly do you want. You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is on a change of the clicked state of the cell in the first table  find its containing rows index in table 1 then toggle a highlight class both in that row and in the row with the same index (if there is one) in the second table.

This is a simple JS snippet to illustrate the idea:

```js
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('table');
const rows1 = tables[0].querySelectorAll('tr');
const rows2 = tables[1].querySelectorAll('tr');

function clicked(el1) {
  const row = el1.parentElement.parentElement;
  let clickedIndex;
  for (clickedIndex = 0; clickedIndex < rows1.length; clickedIndex++) {
    if (rows1[clickedIndex] == row) break;
  }
  rows1[clickedIndex].classList.toggle('highlight');
  if (clickedIndex < rows2.length) rows2[clickedIndex].classList.toggle('highlight');
}
```

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
}

table:nth-child(2) {
  height: 6em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.highlight {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="clicked(this);"></td>
      <td>First row first table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="clicked(this);"></td>
      <td>Second row first table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="clicked(this);"></td>
      <td>Third row first table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="clicked(this);"></td>
      <td>Fourth row first table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <td>First row second table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <td>Second row second table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <td>Third row second table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <td>Fourth row second table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <td>Fifth row second table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <td>Sixth row second table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly what you should do without any code sample, but sounds like a simple thing [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) would take care of.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
```

Then just handle the table's backgroundColor based on the state.